# serve pdf files using node js & express

Tags: node.js, pdf, express

All the PDF files are saved in the filesystem on the server, how to make the files to be downloadable in client side.

for Ex :

```
 app.use('/pdfDownload', function(req, res){
  var pathToTheFile = req.body.fileName;
   readFile(pathToTheFile, function(data){
      //code to make the data to be downloadable;
    });
 });
```

is the request made

```
function readFile(pathToTheFile, cb){
   var fs = require('fs');
   fs.readFile(pathToTheFile, function(err, data){
      //how to make the file fetched to be downloadable in the client requested
      //cb(data);
   }); 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `express.static`, set it up early in your app:

```
app.use('/pdf', express.static(__dirname + '/pathToPDF'));
```

And it will automatically do the job for you when browser navigates to e.g. '/pdf/fooBar.pdf'.

Comment: @Makisms but what about the 'pathToTheFile' it'll be retrieved using the req object

Comment: Static will resolve it automatically. So if you go to `/pdf/test.pdf` then it will try to find file `/pathToPDF/test.pdf`.

Comment: sorry bro i couldn't get you,
If all the files are in /tmp/files/pdf directory.
And the filename in the req is like ObjectId.pdf
how will it flow ? could you please explain 
thanks

Comment: I understood you're comment, i think i'm doing a wrong request from clien side 
`$.get('/pathToPDF/fileName.pdf', function(data){
 
});`
is it correct ?

Comment: You want to open PDF as new tab? Or what you want to get on client side? As well if all files are in /tmp/files/pdf, then you need to do: `app.use('/pdf', express.static('/tmp/files/pdf'));`. Express will resolve the end of url and will get the right file. Just set up express, and then try to navigate in browser to pdf file.

Comment: Thanks man, that helped allot i was getting confused.
i wanted to open pdf in new tab, achieved it using <a> tag and href attribute was the url to the file.

Comment: Yep, that is a straight forward solution. If you need to open pdf using JS, do same but use `window.open`.